# Android DexGuard: Exclude Crashlytics from Obfuscation

Tags: android, obfuscation, crashlytics, dexguard

My application can run perfectly with Crashlytics when I turn DexGuard off. However, when I add the following configurations to obfuscate my code the application stucks at launch with a black screen.

Here is the related part of the **build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'dexguard'

repositories {
  maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
   compile project(':MyProject')
   compile('commons-validator:commons-validator:1.4.0') {
      exclude group: 'commons-logging', module: 'commons-logging'
   }

   compile project(':android-maps-extensions')
   compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.1@aar') {
      transitive = true;
   }
}

android {
   publishNonDefault true
   compileSdkVersion 23
   buildToolsVersion "23"
   compileOptions {
      encoding "windows-1254"
   }

   defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.x.y"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 22
    multiDexEnabled true
   }
   lintOptions {
      abortOnError false
      checkReleaseBuilds false
   }

   dexOptions{
      incremental true
      javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
      jumboMode  true
   }

   android.enforceUniquePackageName = false

   buildTypes {
      debug {
         minifyEnabled false
       }
       release {
          minifyEnabled true
          proguardFiles getDefaultDexGuardFile('dexguard-release.pro'),'dexguard-project.txt'
       }
   }
}
```

Base **build.gradle** file:

```
buildscript {
   repositories {
      flatDir dirs: System.getenv('DEXGUARD_LIB')
      jcenter()
      maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
   }

   dependencies {
      classpath ':dexguard'
      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
      classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
   }
}
```

Related part of **dexguard-project.txt** file:

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*
-multidex

-keep class com.crashlytics.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.crashlytics.**
```

Logcat Console output:

```
Could not find method com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics.getInstance, referenced from method com.x.y.application.MyApplication.ʻ
Could not find method com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics.getInstance, referenced from method com.x.y.application.MyApplication.ˏ
Could not find method com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics.getInstance, referenced from method com.x.y.application.MyApplication.ᐝ

Starting window AppWindowToken{4518e2c0 token=Token{43255cd8 ActivityRecord{42d2a290 u0 com.x.y.tst/com.x.y.activity.start.FirstActivity t369}}} timed out
```

What i am actually doing with Crashlytics.getInstance :

```
Crashlytics.getInstance().core.setString("ENVIRONMENT", "TEST");
```

I see no warnings or errors in the build log.
Anyone have an idea what causes the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried applying the `io.fabric` after `dexguard`?

I have an app working with dexguard and crashlytics and `Crashlytics.getInstance().core.setString("ENVIRONMENT", BuildConfig.BUILD_TYPE);` doesn't cause an error. I'm using the same `-keep` and `-dontwarn` config as you.

From my `build.gradle` file

`apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'dexguard'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'`

Comment: Thank you! This fixed the issue for me.

Comment: I have tried this but no luck. For now I removed the unnecessary components of GooglePlayServices and the number of references reduced below 65k. Thanks for the reply anyway.